# jQuery animate in infinite loop

Tags: jquery, forms, animation, loops

I'm trying to make this happen:

1. prevent a submit button from submitting the form
2. fade an element out
3. then submitting the form

But am stuck with an infinite loop of animation! Why??

HTML

```
<form id="postitron" method="post" action="/postitron/answertron.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="acces" value"yes">
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="DOIT">
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#postitron').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#page').animate({opacity:0},400, function(){
        $('#postitron').submit();
    });
});
```

P.S.- I've also tried the `.one()` method instead of `.submit()`, but it prevents the submit method from being executed on #postitron once the animation's complete :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are binding your event on `SUBMIT`, and your `.animate callback function` is `SUBMIT`'ing the form...causing the infinite loop.

**Try this :**

Instead of binding event `.submit` on `form`, bind `.click` event on `submit` button.

```
$('#submit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#page').animate({opacity:0},400, function(){
        $('#postitron').submit();
    });
});
```

*Bare in mind I did not test this.*

Comment: If you hit `<enter>` within an input box in the form, the form would submit without the animation.

Comment: Nice thought, but is returning an error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function

Comment: Edited to note that the click is on the submit button, not on the form.

Answer (score 0):

`submit()` calls your custom bound `submit` function, which in turns call your `submit` again etc.

Try using DOM's submit:

`$('#postitron')[0].submit()`

Comment: ah.. logical. now the animation completes, but the form doesn't post (it should be 404'ing in my test). Any thoughts?

Comment: hhm, how do you know it's not submitting? Console?

Comment: Yes sir: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'submit' of object #<HTMLFormElement> is not a function

Comment: @technopeasant the crystal ball tells me that you have, somewhere in your form, a form element with `name="submit"`, now do you?

Comment: no sir, I'm using the above code. I do have an element who's ID and Type are set to submit

Answer (score 0):

You could pre-define the function, and within it, unbind to submit, then re-submit.  It's a hack, but it may work.

Or perhaps you check for it's hidden-ness and then resubmit like this:

```
var hidden = false;
$('#postitron').submit(function(e){
    if ( !hidden ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#page').animate({opacity:0},400, function(){
            hidden = true;
            $('#postitron').submit();
        });
    }
});
```